# Reduce the size of a Delete statement in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, query-optimization, sql-delete

I have the below delete statement as scheduled query and it takes ~270GB to execute. The insert statement for the same dates is much smaller.

Is there a reason that the delete statement is so big and can it be optimized somehow?

```
DELETE FROM `TABLE`
 WHERE date BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)) 
   AND FORMAT_DATE( "%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the proposal, Poala!
Unfortunately it did not have any effect on the size of the delete statement however i have partitioned the table by date and this has greatly affected the performance!

It has reduced the size to only ~3GB.

Answer (score 0):

The resource usage of a DELETE statement in BigQuery can be impacted by multiple factors. In your situation, the provided statement appears relatively straightforward, focusing on a particular date range for the purpose of deletion. Also try to consider deleting them in smaller batches. This can help prevent resource exhaustion and better manage the transactional impact.

This code revision eliminates the need for the `FORMAT_DATE` function in the date intervals since the `DATE_SUB` function alone adequately calculates the required date range. It's advisable to refrain from employing functions such as **FORMAT_DATE** within the `WHERE` clause, as they could hinder the query optimizer from effectively utilizing partition pruning.

```
DELETE FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) 
               AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

In case your `INSERT` statement involves **streaming inserts**, it might exhibit greater efficiency in terms of resource consumption compared to a bulk insert. BigQuery's streaming inserts are specifically tailored for managing **real-time data**, whereas bulk inserts could potentially carry additional overhead.

UPDATE:
As per @Mikhail Berlyant, the code error that will be encountered with this workaround will be corrected by:

```
WHERE PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() - 5 AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

I changed my answer into Community Wiki, for additional information on other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.

Comment: you most likely will get following error - `No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: STRING, DATE, DATE. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY)` - To fix this  - you wold rather use `WHERE PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() - 5 AND CURRENT_DATE() - 2`

Comment: Meantime, I think it is not clear what exactly user is asking for! :o)